# Loading XAML into a control at runtime and using the control's resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There's quite a few questions about loading XAML at runtime here,
but as far I can tell this is not a duplicate.

I'm loading XAML into a control at runtime:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Layout.View, Converter={StaticResource StringToXamlConverter}}"/>
```

The converter is rather simple:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    string xaml;
    if (value != null)
    {
        xaml = value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        xaml = Settings.Default.DefaultLayoutView;
    }

    var root = XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
    return root;
}
```

Now, in the XAML that is being loaded, I need to make use of ValueConverters.
The converters are defined as resources of the Window in to which the XAML is loaded. For example:

```
<c:BooleanToVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Of course, the XamlReader.Parse() method throws an exception if I try to use this resource as at the time of reading it is not available.

```
Visibility="{Binding Layout.TextItem1.IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Is there a way to get around this?
Perhaps a way to tell the XamlReader to ignore this?
Or an alternative to ValueConverters that might work in this situation?

Please note, using a DynamicResource does not work either. They cannot be used for ValueConverters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***UPDATED***

OK, You are right, dynamic resources will not work. I have come up with two solutions, and the best part is, I have tested and both will actually work.

Choice 1: Define the static resource in the application resources app.xaml

Choice 2: Do not use a static resource for the converter, just create the converter in the xaml. Sorry for not going off the xaml you were using, but you'll get the idea:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <controls:BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>                   
    </Button.Visibility>

    <Button.Tag>
        <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

Comment: That answer was here before, it does not work. DynamicResource cannot be used for a ValueConverter.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer with two working solutions